How to append tolerations as dictionary in the yaml file
I have a YAML file which creates Daemonset in the kubernetes cluster but there's no toleration block in the code which doesn't guarantee to create the daemonset for spot instances. That is why I need to append tolerations after a certain string before deploying the YAMl file through Pipeline.
The Sample YAML is as follow
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: DaemonSet
  metadata:
    annotations:
      deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: "4"
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"DaemonSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"twistlock-defender-ds","namespace":"twistlock"},"spec":{"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"twistlock-defender"}},"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/twistlock-defender":"unconfined"},"labels":{"app":"twistlock-defender"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"WS_ADDRESS","value":"wss://us-east1.cloud.twistlock.com:443"},{"name":"DEFENDER_TYPE","value":"cri"},{"name":"LOG_PROD","value":"true"},{"name":"SYSTEMD_ENABLED","value":"false"},{"name":"DOCKER_CLIENT_ADDRESS","value":"/var/run/docker.sock"},{"name":"DEFENDER_CLUSTER_ID","value":"b86802a4-e576-393f-8f52-c90ae7764796"},{"name":"DEFENDER_CLUSTER","value":"AZJAPNJE01KUB12991DV01"},{"name":"MONITOR_SERVICE_ACCOUNTS","value":"true"},{"name":"MONITOR_ISTIO","value":"false"},{"name":"COLLECT_POD_LABELS","value":"true"},{"name":"INSTALL_BUNDLE","value":"eyJzZWNyZXRzIjp7fSwiZ2xvYmFsUHJveHlPcHQiOnsiaHR0cFByb3h5IjoiIiwibm9Qcm94eSI6IiIsImNhIjoiIiwidXNlciI6IiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjp7ImVuY3J5cHRlZCI6IiJ9fSwiY3VzdG9tZXJJRCI6InVzLTItMTU4Mjg4NjU5IiwiYXBpS2V5IjoiT0JBVU5hTmFSZ29ZQTB4YmpMUVl4cGlDd0wraU9LZXZqbnhUUW5JYjQ3eFh0U3cwSStTelZ6WDdIeVp0cDNBOWdrRVBvNjhMZURFeXpTai95L2NvSnc9PSIsIm1pY3Jvc2VnQ29tcGF0aWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9"},{"name":"HOST_CUSTOM_COMPLIANCE_ENABLED","value":"false"},{"name":"CLOUD_HOSTNAME_ENABLED","value":"false"},{"name":"FIPS_ENABLED","value":"false"}],"image":"registry-auth.twistlock.com/tw_o0bftrujy5daxq309xzzdpwtmbbbexix/twistlock/defender:defender_32_00_159","name":"twistlock-defender","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"900m","memory":"512Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"256m"}},"securityContext":{"capabilities":{"add":["NET_ADMIN","NET_RAW","SYS_ADMIN","SYS_PTRACE","SYS_CHROOT","MKNOD","SETFCAP","IPC_LOCK"]},"privileged":true,"readOnlyRootFilesystem":true},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/var/lib/twistlock","name":"data-folder"},{"mountPath":"/var/lib/twistlock/certificates","name":"certificates"},{"mountPath":"/var/run","name":"docker-sock-folder"},{"mountPath":"/etc/passwd","name":"passwd","readOnly":true},{"mountPath":"/dev/log","name":"syslog-socket"},{"mountPath":"/var/lib/containers","name":"cri-data"},{"mountPath":"/run","name":"runc-proxy-sock-folder"}]}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirstWithHostNet","hostNetwork":true,"hostPID":true,"restartPolicy":"Always","serviceAccountName":"twistlock-service","volumes":[{"name":"certificates","secret":{"defaultMode":256,"secretName":"twistlock-secrets"}},{"hostPath":{"path":"/dev/log"},"name":"syslog-socket"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/var/lib/twistlock"},"name":"data-folder"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/etc/passwd"},"name":"passwd"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/var/run"},"name":"docker-sock-folder"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/var/lib/containers"},"name":"cri-data"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/run"},"name":"runc-proxy-sock-folder"}]}}}}
    creationTimestamp: "2023-02-22T02:46:26Z"
    generation: 4
    name: twistlock-defender-ds
    namespace: twistlock
    resourceVersion: "436660488"
    uid: d6d72814-86a6-4186-8046-73e20c183c36
  spec:
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: twistlock-defender
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/twistlock-defender: unconfined
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: twistlock-defender
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: WS_ADDRESS
            value: wss://us-east1.cloud.twistlock.com:443
          - name: DEFENDER_TYPE
            value: cri
          - name: LOG_PROD
            value: "true"
          - name: SYSTEMD_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: DOCKER_CLIENT_ADDRESS
            value: /var/run/docker.sock
          - name: DEFENDER_CLUSTER_ID
            value: b86802a4-e576-393f-8f52-c90ae7764796
          - name: DEFENDER_CLUSTER
            value: AZJAPNJE01KUB12991DV01
          - name: MONITOR_SERVICE_ACCOUNTS
            value: "true"
          - name: MONITOR_ISTIO
            value: "false"
          - name: COLLECT_POD_LABELS
            value: "true"
          - name: INSTALL_BUNDLE
            value: eyJzZWNyZXRzIjp7fSwiZ2xvYmFsUHJveHlPcHQiOnsiaHR0cFByb3h5IjoiIiwibm9Qcm94eSI6IiIsImNhIjoiIiwidXNlciI6IiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjp7ImVuY3J5cHRlZCI6IiJ9fSwiY3VzdG9tZXJJRCI6InVzLTItMTU4Mjg4NjU5IiwiYXBpS2V5IjoiT0JBVU5hTmFSZ29ZQTB4YmpMUVl4cGlDd0wraU9LZXZqbnhUUW5JYjQ3eFh0U3cwSStTelZ6WDdIeVp0cDNBOWdrRVBvNjhMZURFeXpTai95L2NvSnc9PSIsIm1pY3Jvc2VnQ29tcGF0aWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9
          - name: HOST_CUSTOM_COMPLIANCE_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: CLOUD_HOSTNAME_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: FIPS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          image: registry-auth.twistlock.com/tw_o0bftrujy5daxq309xzzdpwtmbbbexix/twistlock/defender:defender_32_00_159
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: twistlock-defender
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 900m
              memory: 512Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 256m
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              add:
              - NET_ADMIN
              - NET_RAW
              - SYS_ADMIN
              - SYS_PTRACE
              - SYS_CHROOT
              - MKNOD
              - SETFCAP
              - IPC_LOCK
            privileged: true
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/twistlock
            name: data-folder
          - mountPath: /var/lib/twistlock/certificates
            name: certificates
          - mountPath: /var/run
            name: docker-sock-folder
          - mountPath: /etc/passwd
            name: passwd
            readOnly: true
          - mountPath: /dev/log
            name: syslog-socket
          - mountPath: /var/lib/containers
            name: cri-data
          - mountPath: /run
            name: runc-proxy-sock-folder
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true
        hostPID: true
        restartPolicy: Always
        schedulerName: default-scheduler
        securityContext: {}
        serviceAccount: twistlock-service
        serviceAccountName: twistlock-service
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        volumes:
        - name: certificates
          secret:
            defaultMode: 256
            secretName: twistlock-secrets
        - hostPath:
            path: /dev/log
            type: ""
          name: syslog-socket
        - hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/twistlock
            type: ""
          name: data-folder
        - hostPath:
            path: /etc/passwd
            type: ""
          name: passwd
        - hostPath:
            path: /var/run
            type: ""
          name: docker-sock-folder
        - hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/containers
            type: ""
          name: cri-data
        - hostPath:
            path: /run
            type: ""
          name: runc-proxy-sock-folder
    updateStrategy:
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 0
        maxUnavailable: 1
      type: RollingUpdate
  status:
    currentNumberScheduled: 6
    desiredNumberScheduled: 6
    numberAvailable: 6
    numberMisscheduled: 0
    numberReady: 6
    observedGeneration: 4
    updatedNumberScheduled: 6
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""

I tried below PowerShell Script to append the tolerations after terminationGracePeriodSeconds but that didn't append the Toleration. The pipeline was run successfully & toleration appended successfully message we got but might be some mistake in the code.
         ### Append toleration to defender.yaml yaml ###
          $yamlFilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/defender.yaml"
          $yamlContent = Get-Content $yamlFilePath

          # Define the tolerations block as an array of strings
          # Define the tolerations block as an array of strings
          $tolerationYaml = @"
           tolerations:
           - operator: "Exists"
          "@

          # Create a new array to hold the modified YAML content
          $modifiedYamlContent = @()
          
          # Loop through each line and insert the toleration block after "terminationGracePeriodSeconds"
          foreach ($line in $yamlContent) {
              $modifiedYamlContent += $line
              
              if ($line -match "^\s*terminationGracePeriodSeconds:.*$") {
                  $modifiedYamlContent += $tolerationYaml
              }
          }

          # Print yaml file
          Get-content -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/defender.yaml
         
          # Write the modified content back to the YAML file
          $modifiedYamlContent | Set-Content $yamlFilePath
          Write-Host "Toleration appended successfully to $yamlFilePath"

Any idea how to fix it?

May i suggest to use a Module to import\export YAML files? It seems the easiest way to do this, there are a few on Powershell Gallery

To add a new block after terminationGracePeriodSeconds in your YAML, you can try the PowerShell scripts below.
The PowerShell scripts file update.ps1
# Define the path to your YAML file
$yamlFilePath = "defender.yaml"

# Read the YAML file content
$yamlContent = Get-Content -Path $yamlFilePath -Raw

# Define the new block to be added
$newBlock = @"
        tolerations:
          - operator: "Exists"
"@

# Insert the new block after terminationGracePeriodSeconds
$updatedYamlContent = $yamlContent -replace "(terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30)", "`$1`n$newBlock"

# Write the updated content back to the YAML file
Set-Content -Path $yamlFilePath -Value $updatedYamlContent

# Output the updated YAML content (optional)
Write-Output $updatedYamlContent

Azure Pipeline yaml file:
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: 'update.ps1'

Result:


Thank you for providing the improved code @Ziyang Liu-MSFT. I tried it out & was able to append toleration after terminationGracePeriodSeconds but the format seems broken. It appended the toleration from the beginning of the line not exactly in the same indentation.
Any idea how can we append in the same indentation otherwise toleration is not honored? Sorry for asking too much.

Hi @Md sabbir Ahmed, are you using the same block as shared by me? The block already contains the indentation. The actual result is consistent with the screenshot and should be the format you expect. Feel free to let me know if you have any question or need any help.

It worked finally, thank you for your great support @Ziyang Liu-MSF. It was the garbage char which was creating the issue. Now the indentation is same as expected & the object creation with toleration was successful. Thank you again!
